# Is there a Scala equivalent of Haskell's Data.These (A, B, or (A and B))?

Tags: scala

Summary of the Haskell [these](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/these) package:

> The 'These' type represents values with two non-exclusive possibilities

```
data These a b = This a | That b | These a b
```

Is there anything similar in Scala? Maybe in scalaz?

For those unfamiliar with Haskell, here's a rough sketch of how one might approach this in Scala:

```
sealed trait These[+A, +B] {
  def thisOption: Option[A]
  def thatOption: Option[B]
}

trait ThisLike[+A] {
  def `this`: A
  def thisOption = Some(a)
}

trait ThatLike[+B] {
  def `that`: B
  def thatOption = Some(b)
}

case class This[+A](`this`: A) extends These[A, Nothing] with ThisLike[A] {
  def thatOption = None
}

case class That[+B](`that`: B) extends These[Nothing, B] with ThatLike[B] {
  def thisOption = None
}

case class Both[+A, +B](`this`: A, `that`: B) extends These[A, B]
  with ThisLike[A] with ThatLike[B]
```

Or you could do something like combining `Either`s:

```
type These[A, B] = Either[Either[A, B], (A, B)]
```

(Obviously, expressing the data structure is not difficult. But if there's something already well thought-out in an existing in a library, I'd prefer to just use it.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

scalaz has these, which is also referred to as `\&/`

https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/These.scala

Comment: and here's the doc: http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/stable/7.1.0-M3/doc/#scalaz.$bslash$amp$div

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I wish scalaz weren't so big into symbolic names. It makes everything hard to search for.